# SQL row level security policy

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, row, policy

I have a database with following structure:

Data:

| Employee | Department |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |

Users

| Manager | Department |
| --- | --- |
| yyy | 1 |
| yyy | 2 |
| xxx | 2 |
| zzz | 3 |

So manager yyy, has access to all rows with department 1 or 2. Manager xxx has access to rows with department 2, zzz to department 3.

I'm trying to construct a function and security policy accordingly, but with no success.

This select statement works correct, but I want to implement it as RLS:

```
select * 
from Data as D
join Users as U on U.department = D.department
where U.manager = USER_NAME()
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data seems incorrectly matched (I see no rows in `Data` for department 3, so `yyy` returns all rows). But here is what I think you're looking for:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckManager
(
  @Department int
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
  RETURN
  (
    SELECT Allow = 1
      FROM dbo.Users
      WHERE Department = @Department
        AND Manager = USER_NAME()
  );
GO

CREATE SECURITY POLICY dbo.ManagersPolicy
ADD FILTER PREDICATE dbo.CheckManager(Department)
ON dbo.Data WITH (STATE = ON);
GO
```

Comment: It works. Thx. My next problem is, that the website that retrieves data, runs via a webserver with a service account. So its the service users rights that queryes data from sql and not the real user: $connectionOptions = array(
            "Database" => 'Database',
            "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8",
            "Uid" => 'Serviceuser',
            "PWD" => 'Kodeord',
            "TrustServerCertificate" => true
        );

Comment: @BrianMøller Well, you need to tell SQL Server who the real user is _somehow_. Maybe using [`SESSION_CONTEXT`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4094/phase-out-contextinfo-in-sql-server-2016-with-sessioncontext/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)? If the app is connecting as a service account, there's no way for SQL Server to know who is at the other end.

Comment: There is Windows Authentication on the webserver, so I have $_SERVER['AUTH_USER']; from the user logged on. But cant really see how it helps me with RLS. I cant be the first with this specific issue

Comment: If you can get that to SQL Server somehow (e.g. through `SESSION_CONTEXT`, it can help for sure - then the RLS function can just pull it from there (it's very much like a session variable on a web site). Other hacky ways to get it to SQL Server are to append it to application name in the connection string, then RLS can use `PROGRAM_NAME()`. That's tougher to test, though.

Comment: I cant get this to work. My user see all rows despite I shouldnt have access to only some rows:

Comment: @BrianMøller I can't really help without a repro and an explanation of how you are telling RLS who the real user is. If everyone looks like the service account, they're all going to see the same rows.